# Add one last tab to a sortable tabbed list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I'm using twitter bootstrap, knockout, knockout-sortable, and JQuery UI (also haml but it's inconsequential to the question). I display a tabbed list like the following. It adds a final tab with a button inside.

```
%ul.nav.nav-tabs
  /ko foreach: pages
  %li
    %span{ "data-bind" => "text: name()" }
  / /ko
  %li
    %button.btn
      %i.icon-plus
```

I'm trying to make the tabs sortable (via dragging) but I'm running into problems with the button:

```
%ul.nav.nav-tabs{ "data-bind" => "sortable: pages" }
  %li
    %span{ "data-bind" => "text: name()" }
  /%li
  /  %button.btn
  /    %i.icon-plus
```

I can't use `/ko sortable: pages` because it doesn't work (`The binding 'sortable' cannot be used with virtual elements`). How can I achieve the same effect (last tab being a button) with sortable? Can't move the final tab/button though.

The answer may not have to be adding a tab, it could be adding an element that appears at the end of the tabs.

**Update:**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pbNvz/6/

Comment: Maybe put together a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) can do the job for you, here is the updated fiddle :

http://jsbin.com/edopuh/3/edit

For excluding any particular li element from sortable element you can use [items](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items) option of jquery ui sortable plugin, it accepts jquery selectors.

**Update**

For doing something after moving item you can use [Update event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) of jquery ui sortable. Check this updated fiddle, in this fiddle after moving item you will get the alert :

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/edopuh/8/edit)

Comment: Nice, is there a way to use afterMove? e.g. ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.afterMove = function(arg) { alert('moved one!'); }; I tried to add it to your example but couldn't.