# Getting underlying object after jquery sort

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I can get the UI element that was moved with the following JS Bin code but not the JS object.

http://jsbin.com/edopuh/14/edit

```
ko.bindingHandlers.Sortable = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor() || {});
      $(element).sortable({
        items: 'li:not(".notsortable")',
        update: function(event, ui){
           alert("you just moved " +  $(ui.item[0]).text());
        }
      });
    }
};
```

After a move is made, how can I get the list of Person objects and the new positions?

Comment: You want to get the position of the newly moved item?

Comment: What *exactly* are you missing and trying to get access to? The bindings for the element that was moved?

Comment: For similar functionality, you might want to check out: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

Comment: @GotDibbs I'm trying to save each Person's position when an item is moved. To do that I need each Person object and their new positions. The Person object of the example only has name and age (for simplicity) but my object has many properties used to save it (id, parent, etc.).

Comment: @RPNiemeyer The problem is that I can't make knockout-sortable keep the last item on a list fixed. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734263/add-one-last-tab-to-a-sortable-tabbed-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted in the comments, you're looking to save each Person's position in the sortable once they are moved. In order to do so you need to access the model attached to the DOM element that is being moved. Knockout provides a utility function to gain access to the View Model associated to an element called [`ko.dataFor([elem])`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html).

In order to obtain the index of the moved element, you simply need to invoke jQuery's [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function on the moved item.

I've updated your example here to demonstrate how to use the two in concert for your situation: http://jsbin.com/edopuh/27/edit

```
ko.bindingHandlers.Sortable = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor() || {});
      $(element).sortable({
        items: 'li:not(".notsortable")',
        update: function(event, ui){
           var $item = $(ui.item[0]),
               person = ko.dataFor(ui.item[0]);

           alert("you just moved " +  $item.text());

           person.position = $item.index();
        }
      });
  }
};
```